# glibc detected error in matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, glibc, matrix-multiplication

I wrote a simple C++ code for matrix multiplication. The code is giving a glib c error. It is a simple matrix multiplication code to multiply two matrices.

```
#include <iostream>
 using std::cerr;
 using std::cout;
 using std::endl;
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 using std::string;
#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cmath>
#include<math.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
int i,j,k;
vector<int> mult;
vector<float> dist_shell;
std::string skip;
std::string empty_line;
std::string num_elements[3];
int cluster_num;
vector<int> inter_type; //Interaction type (2-2body;3-3body etc.)
int c_mult;
float c_dist_shell;
int c_inter_type; // c stands for cin type variables frm reading file 
float unit_cell[3][3];
float factor;
int l,m,n;
float sum;

ifstream poscar("POSCAR");


float unit_cell[3][3];

    int total_atom=32;
    float frac[total_atom][3];
    float real_pos[total_atom][3];
    for (int count=0;count<total_atom;count++)
        {
    poscar>>frac[count][1]>>frac[count][2]>>frac[count][3]>>true_false[count][1]>>true_false[count][2]>>true_false[count][3];
                }     
        for (l=0;l<total_atom;l++)
                {
                for (m=0;m<3;m++)
                    {
                        sum=0;
                    for (n=0;n<3;n++)
                        {
                            sum+=frac[l][n]*unit_cell[n][m];
                        }
                    real_pos[l][m]=sum;
                    }
                }

return 0;
}
```

My error is:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00002aaaaadb8b88 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x2aaaab0b676e]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_free+0x6c)[0x2aaaab0b7ebc]
/usr/intel/pkgs/gcc/4.2.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSs7reserveEm+0x9e)[0x2aaaaac657fe]
/usr/intel/pkgs/gcc/4.2.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSs6appendEPKcm+0x66)[0x2aaaaac659c6]
/usr/intel/pkgs/gcc/4.2.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZStrsIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEERSt13basic_ist
reamIT_T0_ES7_RSbIS4_S5_T1_E+0x1a9)[0x2aaaaac3fdb9]
./a.out[0x4022ec]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4)[0x2aaaab068304]
./a.out(__gxx_personality_v0+0x69)[0x401019]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00405000 r-xp 00000000 00:109 14247450                          /nfs/site/disks/summ
er11/counting/counting_main/a.out
00505000-00506000 rw-p 00005000 00:109 14247450                          /nfs/site/disks/summ
er11/counting/counting_main/a.out
00506000-00527000 rw-p 00506000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
2aaaaaaab000-2aaaaaac6000 r-xp 00000000 68:02 80782                      /lib64/ld-2.4.so
2aaaaaac6000-2aaaaaac7000 r-xp 2aaaaaac6000 00:00 0 
2aaaaaac7000-2aaaaaac9000 rw-p 2aaaaaac7000 00:00 0 
2aaaaabc6000-2aaaaabc8000 rw-p 0001b000 68:02 80782                      /lib64/ld-2.4.so
2aaaaabc8000-2aaaaacb0000 r-xp 00000000 00:18 2295681                    /nfs/sc/itools/em64t
_SLES10/pkgs/gcc/4.2.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.9
2aaaaacb0000-2aaaaadaf000 ---p 000e8000 00:18 2295681                    /nfs/sc/itools/em64t
_SLES10/pkgs/gcc/4.2.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.9
2aaaaadaf000-2aaaaadb6000 r--p 000e7000 00:18 2295681                    /nfs/sc/itools/em64t
_SLES10/pkgs/gcc/4.2.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.9
2aaaaadb6000-2aaaaadb8000 rw-p 000ee000 00:18 2295681                    /nfs/sc/itools/em64t
_SLES10/pkgs/gcc/4.2.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.9
2aaaaadb8000-2aaaaadcd000 rw-p 2aaaaadb8000 00:00 0 
2aaaaade8000-2aaaaae3c000 r-xp 00000000 68:02 80502                      /lib64/libm-2.4.so
2aaaaae3c000-2aaaaaf3b000 ---p 00054000 68:02 80502                      /lib64/libm-2.4.so
2aaaaaf3b000-2aaaaaf3d000 rw-p 00053000 68:02 80502                      /lib64/libm-2.4.so
2aaaaaf3d000-2aaaaaf3e000 rw-p 2aaaaaf3d000 00:00 0 
2aaaaaf3e000-2aaaaaf4b000 r-xp 00000000 00:18 1094438                    /nfs/sc/itools/em64t
_SLES10/pkgs/gcc/4.2.2/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
2aaaaaf4b000-2aaaab04a000 ---p 0000d000 00:18 1094438                    /nfs/sc/itools/em64t
_SLES10/pkgs/gcc/4.2.2/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
2aaaab04a000-2aaaab04b000 rw-p 0000c000 00:18 1094438                    /nfs/sc/itools/em64t
_SLES10/pkgs/gcc/4.2.2/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
2aaaab04b000-2aaaab182000 r-xp 00000000 68:02 80494                      /lib64/libc-2.4.so
2aaaab182000-2aaaab282000 ---p 00137000 68:02 80494                      /lib64/libc-2.4.so
2aaaab282000-2aaaab285000 r--p 00137000 68:02 80494                      /lib64/libc-2.4.so
2aaaab285000-2aaaab287000 rw-p 0013a000 68:02 80494                      /lib64/libc-2.4.so
2aaaab287000-2aaaab28e000 rw-p 2Abort
```

I am trying to figure out if there is an error in another part of my code. Changing datatypes also did not help. Thanks to everyone who can help me with spotting the error.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751940/problem-with-containers-glibc-detected-free-invalid-pointer-0x41e0c might give some hints

Comment: How is `unit_cell` defined? If you could post a whole, compilable example, that would help, since this kind of error (memory corruption, most likely) may well be caused by something at a seemingly unrelated position in the code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont see where my invalid pointer is. Can you please point it out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where are you calling the `free` function?  Or possibly `realloc`?  Calls to `free` don't just materialize out of thin air.  Are you compiling your code with debugging information enabled (the `-g` option with GCC)?  Have you tried using a debugger and/or Valgrind?

Comment: Your code as posted does not compile -- total_atom has not been declared -- it has to be a const value. E.g. `const int total_atom=32;`

Comment: I fixed the total_atom error...but I doubt glibC is giving an error because of that.

Comment: THank you for all your downvotes. I am a novice and I tried my best to learn and ask relevant questions. Didnt know one would be thrown out of a community and unable to ask/learn anything. Thanks again.

Comment: Fixed the error. Thanks for making me self-reliant. But really, please unblock me. I have seen far worse questions being asked on this forum. I see no reason for me to be removed. Everyone has a learning curve!

Comment: @user1705329: You are not being "blocked".  I did not downvote the question, but the people who did probably did so because it omitted important details and was not very well-asked.  A great way to ask a question is to provide a [short, self-contained, correct, compilable example](http://sscce.org/) of a program that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that while reading some lines from a file, getline sometimes reads end of the line and not the next line. So it is important to check what exactly the line skipping part contains. That has led to this error in the end. The error was not a part of this code.